# NuxtJS build breaks with UglifyJS and node-rsa. How do I resolve this?

Tags: node.js, webpack, nuxt.js, uglifyjs

I'm using the library node-rsa (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa) in a NuxtJS project. When building for production using the command `nuxt build` (which includes minification of JS and CSS by default), the build process breaks near the end with the following message:

```
ERROR in 0.nuxt.bundle.7c6932a7a42bdaaa7fa4.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (pem) [./~/node-rsa/src/formats/pkcs1.js:55,0][0.nuxt.bundle.7c6932a7a42bdaaa7fa4.js:42640,20]
Error: Webpack build exited with errors
    at /home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/nuxt/dist/nuxt.js:904:44
    at /home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:267:15
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:362:37)
    at /home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:260:12
    at /home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:355:11
    at next (/home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:154:11)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (/home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/webpack/lib/performance/SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (/home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:158:13)
    at Compiler.afterEmit (/home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:352:8)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:347:14)
    at /home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:460:16
    at iteratorCallback (/home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1034:13)
    at /home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:944:16
    at /home/ubuntu/front-end/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:43:10
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:117:15)
```

I was able to temporarily mitigate the issue by disabling uglifyJS (solution found at https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/250) but that does not seem like a long term solution. What is the correct way to resolve this?

Potentially related issue: [Webpack breaks when i include node-rsa library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689433/webpack-breaks-when-i-include-node-rsa-library)

Comment: What Nuxt version? Latest Nuxt don't use uglifyjs

Comment: Thank you. I was using an older version of NuxtJS, but that was not the root cause of my issue. I have posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I was trying to use a node library (not uglify-safe) on the browser without webpacking it. I switched to using pure JS for my crypto needs and everything went fine.